# Are the Martians saying "Ut" or "Ack"?

Tags: dialogue, mars-attacks

I've watched Mars Attacks plenty of times. Every time I watch it, I always hear "Ut, ut, ut!" when the Martians talk. That's also the sound I make when I imitate them.

However, I've seen all over the place people using "Ack" instead of "Ut". I've listened carefully to their dialogue, and I just don't hear "Ack" at all. I hear "Ut".

Is my hearing impaired? Or is everyone using the wrong word?

**EDIT over 2 years later**

I can't believe I just realized the actual pronunciation I meant to relay is more of an "Uht" just a hard start of more of an "Ahh" sound. Just the pitch of the voice starts off already relatively high.

So really more of an "AHT!" sound mixed with "UHT!".

> Ut ut, ahht!

Comment: FWIW I always heard it as "At", which is sort of a mixture of these two.

Comment: You don't use the phonetic spelling of what you hear. UT as in Tut? Toot (tutorial)?

Comment: @cde Yes, I mean "Ut" as found in "Tut".

Comment: I'm an "At" guy too

Comment: @cde Edited.......

Comment: I dont suppose you mind mentioning your local? Also native english speaker? I have a hard time hearing anything *but* ‘Ack’ an Uut or Uht sound truly alien to me.

Comment: @morbo Native English, born in the US. "an Uut or Uht sound truly alien to me." That's kinda the point :-p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the this interview with screenwriters Scott Alexander and Larry Karaszewski, the Martians are saying "Ack Ack Ack"

Comment: What a shame, I seriously don't hear "Ack" anywhere in the movie :-/

Comment: @JerryDodge Hehe!  I have only seen the movie one time...ages ago.  I will have to re-watch to listen for it now ;)

Comment: @cde Actually I do recall the president (Jack Nickolson) saying something like that.

Comment: Right along the lines of how "What if I told you that the phrase 'what if I told you' is nowhere in the Matrix?" In fact, it's not. The phrase "What if" only appears twice in the entire movie, and neither of them are Morpheus.

Comment: @jerry http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeamMeUpScotty

Comment: I'm hearing ack.

Answer (score 2):

DVD Subtitles say Ack. There is no alternative spelling. Broadcast Close Captioning (for the hearing impaired) also say ACK.

Comment: Valid statement. However, I think your downvote came from someone who thought this answer didn't use any actual evidence or examples beyond what was already mentioned in the question...

Comment: If any of this was in the question they wouldn't have had one.